# Some functions cannot use by OpenMPI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, openmpi

I read a report about MPI Version 3.1. I saw a function called MPI_Win_allocate, so I tried to use it in my vs project. I use OpenMpi on Visual Studio 2010, version is 1.6.1, but it turned that:

> ERROR:Undefined identifier

with `MPI_Win_allocate`, and same problem with `MPI_Win_allocate_shared`, `MPI_Win_shared_query` and so on.

I wonder why it happened, is that because the OpenMPI version is too old and does not suit for MPI Version 3.1? Or does this happen because of some other reasons?

Answer (score 0):

See [the OpenMPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/) documentation.

The function [`MPI_Win_allocate()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man3/MPI_Win_allocate.3.php) is not available in version 1.6+. You need to upgrade to version 1.10+ or, even better, version 2.0+.

Edit: it seems that `MPI_Win_allocate()` is already implemented in version 1.8+, even if it is not documented. The following comment is written in the [description of changes](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi-release/blob/v1.8/NEWS) in version 1.8.3:

> > - Add new MPI-3.1 tools interface

Comment: Oh i see, thank u bro. Umm, i'm sorry i may ask more question cause i'm noob of OpenMPI. I downloaded OpenMPI_v1.6.1-1_win32.exe in www.open-mpi.org for my win 7 system, it's easy for me just install it and can use OpenMPI then. But seems after version 1.6, there r only .src.rpm, .tar.gz and .tar.bz2. I know the rpm is for Linux to install, but i'm not sure that the other two r also for Linux or can use for windows, when i download those two, i just extract them, but i don't know how to use.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! Don't feel sorry about questions: this website is dedicated to programmers having questions! You might be able to use the .tar.gz or tar.bz2 on windows if you use Cygwin or MSYS/MINGW to obtain a GNU like environement for windows. Otherwise, you may try MS-MPI, though I did not  find `MPI_Win_allocate()` is its documentation. Last chance is MPICH2: the version 3.2 seems to handle `MPI_Win_allocate()`, but I don't know if it is possible to use it on windows.

Comment: @Lucky, Open MPI is no longer supported on Windows. The last official build for Windows was from the 1.6.x branch.

Comment: @francis, thank u very much,i'll try the methods u suggested :)

Comment: @Hristo Iliev, i see, thanks a lot, so i better use MPICH2 right?

Comment: @Lucky, if you specifically need `MPI_Win_allocate`, the vanilla MPICH2 is probably the best option.

Comment: @Hristo Iliev, thanks a lot, i'll try to use MPICH2 instead of OpenMpi